# ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "No module named tables"

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

I followed the installation guidelines from here. http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html

So, whenever I run this command in iPython from PyTables/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 folder, it works fine.

`In [1]: import pandas as pd`

`In [2]: store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')`

But whenever I run the same commands from other folders, it gives me the specified error. Is it the PYTHONPATH issue? If yes, how to solve it?

Comment: Did you install it using `pip install tables`?

Answer (score 0):

To know what version of PyTables you are using, execute

```
python -c 'import tables ; print tables.__file__'
```

for Python 2, or

```
python3 -c 'import tables ; print(tables.__file__)'
```

for Python 3.

It will give you the path to the tables library.

The procedure in the link you gave, executing from the build directory, is just to test the tables library.

To install it, use

```
python setup.py install --user
```

It will then go in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-package"` (for Linux and Python 2, as an example). Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: What I really want is to install the package in my virtualenv so that I can access it anywhere. The option you gave still doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: In a virtual env, just `python setup.py install` should do.